# Checkstyle working differently for same condition

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, checkstyle

On applying check style i am getting " hides a field" if the name of formal and actual parameters are same.

```
private String limitedDimensionId;

 /**
 * Sets the limited dimension id.
 * 
 * @param limitedDimensionId
 *            the new limited dimension id
 */
public void setLimitedDimensionId(final String limitedDimensionId) {
    this.limitedDimensionId = limitedDimensionId;
}
```

However i am not getting the same issue in the following case:

```
private boolean fallBack;

 /**
 * @param isFallBack
 *            the isFallBack to set
 */
public void setFallBack(final boolean isFallBack) {
    this.fallBack = isFallBack;
}
```

Both the conditions appear same to me. Still the discrepancy. Usually i change the  name of the parameter variable to resolve this check style issue. But looking at the other case i am getting a hint that a more elegant solution is available. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable names are different:

`fallBack` vs `isFallBack`

> Usually i change the name of the parameter variable to resolve this check style issue

That's correct solution.

Comment: u r so ryt....looks like i need and eye examination before actually programming or looking at anything for that sake....still ain't there any other way of doing so....for a large file (say with 40 variables)...do i have to change the name of each and every one of them individually .. ??

Comment: Yes, i guess. Or may be you can write a plugin for same. :-)

Comment: you can write a plugin to prefix the variables with certain word. and similar things ...

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that giving them different names is more appropriate, however the "this" keyword in the "this.limitedDimensionid" should avoid the "hides a field" error. That's what it's for...